# Redux-Form—Create Password Field with »retype«

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am building a redux form and I would like to create a »Retype Password« field which is rendered next to the password field. I have this code:

```
const renderRow = (field) => {
  return (
    <div className={`form-row ${field.type}`}>
      <label>{field.label}</label>
      <Field field={field} component={renderPassword} name={field.name} />
    </div>
  );
}


const renderPassword = ({field, input, meta: { error, touched }}) => {
  return (
    <div className="password-inputs-wrap">
      <input type="password" {...input} />
      <input type="password" {...input} name="password-retype" />
      {touched && error && <RenderError error={error} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Right now this renders two password fields, but changing one, changes the other at the same time.

The `renderRow` is a bit simplified here, since the component for that field is not hard coded as show here. So this password field is an exception, since it consists of two `<input>`s. For all other fields, which consist of a single `<input>`/`<select />`, etc, it works fine.

How can I »decouple« this retype `<input>` from the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two fields (two `Field`s).

Comment: Could you either extend on this a little or add it as a comment instead? It might be hard for some people to follow your thinking here. Thank you!

Comment: That says: You cannot wrap more than one html form input element within one `<Field />` element. In other words: My approach was wrong, so the thing I wanted to do not possible like that.

Comment: Yes, @philipp understood.